# Why am I getting an error when using split function of javascript?

Tags: javascript, node.js, split

I'm trying to split my string but not get proper output as per my expected.

Input

```
let name = "helloguys";
```

Output

```
h
he
hel
hell
hello
hellog
hellogu
helloguy
helloguys
```

```
let name = "mynameisprogrammer";
for (let index = 1; index <= name.length; index++) {
  let finalData = name.split(name[index]);
  console.log(finalData[0]);
}
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qb8BU.png)

Comment: Sounds like you should be using `substring` instead. Do you expect the code to magically differentiate between splitting on the first or second (or third or fourth) `m`?

Comment: Split your string into what? You need to provide the expected output as well

Comment: Your code is splitting the text at every char, eg.  Split on `m`, split on `y`, split on `n`, etc. etc.   What is your aim?, if you just want to split the text into `['m', 'y', 'n',...]` etc, just do `name.split('')`.

Comment: what do you want to do or get??

Answer (score 0):

You can use [substring](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_substring.asp) to take parts of your input:

```js
let name = "mynameisprogrammer";
for (let index = 1; index <= name.length; index++) {
  let finalData = name.substring(0, index);
  console.log(finalData);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use [`Array.map()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) along with [`String.slice()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/slice) to split the string into the required values:

```js
let name = "mynameisprogrammer";
let result = [...name].map((chr, idx) => name.slice(0, idx + 1));

console.log('Result:', result)
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; }
```

Answer (score 0):

If you need this to be unicode aware, you might want to avoid using string substring / slice etc.

Instead convert to array, and split there.

eg..

```js
let name = "mynameisprogrammer";

const nameA = [...name];
for (let ix = 1; ix <= nameA.length; ix += 1) 
   console.log(nameA.slice(0, ix).join(''));
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; }
```

ps.  To see what I mean by unicode aware, try using the name from the code above into some of the other answers.

Answer (score 0):

You can simply use a variable and keeping add value of current index and keep printing on each iteration, you don't need split here

```js
let name = "helloguys";

function printName(name) {
  let temp = ''
  for (let index = 0; index < name.length; index++) {
    temp += name[index]
    console.log(temp);
  }
}

printName(name)
```

Answer (score 0):

This is how you could do it.
I'm not sure if you wanted them to be object otherwise you could use `string.substring`

```js
let name = "mynameisprogrammer";
for (let index = 0; index < name.length; index++) {
  let finalData = name.split("");
  console.log(finalData.slice(0,index+1).join(""));
}
```